# Use view/layout of the base Fragment

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-fragments

I have an base Fragment with an FrameLayout and I want to use this Layout in the derived Fragment and add an onTouchListener to it.

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected FrameLayout baseFrameLayout;
    protected View baseView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        baseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);

        baseFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) baseView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        return baseView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_base.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

**DerivedFragment.java**

```
public class DerivedFragment extends BaseFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        baseFrameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // do something
                return true;
            }
        });

        return baseView;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the onTouchListener is not executed when I touch the FrameLayout

---

**EDIT:**

Finally I add the DerivedFragment to another Fragment in this way:

**OverViewFragment.java**

```
public class OverViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overView, container, false);

        Fragment derivedFragment = new DerivedFragment();
        FragmentTransaction devTrans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        devTrans.add(R.id.derivedFragmentId, derivedFragment).commit();

        Fragment footerFragment = new FooterFragment();
        FragmentTransaction statTrans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        statTrans.add(R.id.footerFragmentId, footerFragment).commit();

        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_overView.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/derivedFragmentId"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerFragmentId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center" 
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerFragmentId"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @oberflansch no effect, but I've added it to my question :(

Comment: are there any other views above the FrameLayout  ?

Comment: @oberflansch I've edited my question

Comment: Well i don't know... sorry. Just some hints: android:layout_above="@+id/footerFragment" is not referring to an other id in this layout. I guess it should be footerFragmentId? Also the FrameLayouts are wrap_content, with nothing inside. Are you sure they are visible and get clicked?

Comment: I will test it later, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never used empty Layouts before. So i just tested it.

With the following lines the Layout is not visible and does not get clicks:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

The following lines work:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

So either make the Layouts `match_parent` or add views inside.